# Populate Rails PostgreSQL hstore using factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, factory-bot

I'm using Rails 4.2 and [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to populate my test database. I have a model that uses an hstore for some unstructured data. How do I populate the hstore from factory_girl? Is it as simple as passing it a hash?

Initially I tried this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :thingy do
    unstructured_data {
      foo: "foo",
      bar: "bar"
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks you just pass a Hash. I did find thad I had to assign the hash to an object but I probably could have used parens to get that to work too.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :thingy do
    hash = {
      foo: "foo",
      bar: "bar"
    }

    unstructured_data hash
  end
end
```